# What is the Android equivalent of iOS's accessory action?

Tags: usability, interaction-design, android, lists, info-visualisation

I'm developing a cross-platform business app for iOS and Android. Among other features, the app allows users to select a project from a large list (hundreds of entries) of available projects.

Some of these Projects also have additional information, which is not visible while viewing the project list. Upon selecting a project, the user should be able to view the additional Information on the selected Project as well as to select a different Project instead if he needs to.

For iOS, I though of showing the additional info upon clicking an accessory icon:

[image]

For Android I'm not sure what to do. What would you recommend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [Google Material design guidelines](https://material.google.com/components/lists.html#lists-actions).

In Android there seems to be a very similar icon (from the former link) and the way to structure the primary and secondary actions is very similar:

[image]

[Here](https://material.io/icons/) you have more information about Android icons.